# Wear shatnez or eating pork

Tags: sources-mekorot

The Toras Kohanim says:

> A person should not say that he doesn't want to eat pork; rather, [he should say that] he would love [to eat non-kosher meat,] but and that Hashem commanded him [not to]."

where is it?

Comment: You wrote: "I heard some mention that the Toras Kohanim states" and then a quote.  That *mention* that you heard came from somewhere; it's unlikely to be a vague "I heard this somewhere and can't remember" if you have an *exact quote*.  Please provide the source of this "mention".  Thank you.

Comment: Well the account of chiddushei Torah was suspended, I assume for repeatedly asking these sorts of questions and refusing to clarify the source of those quotes, so make sure to edit in your sources.

Comment: I feel that you changed your original question

Comment: I know I've seen this before in Gemara, I just can't remember where...

Comment: @RealTorah I restitued your first question. If you want to ask further, please write a new question.

Answer (score 6):

Torat Cohanim on [Perek 20 Pasuk 26](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%9B#.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7_.D7.9B.D7.95_.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7.29.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7.29)

> [יב] "ואבדיל אתכם מן העמים להיות לי"-- אם מובדלים אתם מן העמים הרי אתם לשמי ואם לאו הרי אתם של נבוכדנצר מלך בבל וחבריו.
>   ר' אלעזר בן עזריה אומר מנין שלא יאמר אדם "אי אפשי ללבוש שעטנז. אי אפשי לאכול בשר חזיר. אי אפשי לבוא על הערוה" אבל "אפשי ומה אעשה ואבי שבשמים גזר עלי כך"? תלמוד לומר "ואבדיל אתכם מן העמים להיות לי"-- נמצא פורש מן העבירה ומקבל עליו עול מלכות שמים. ‏
>
> I will separate you from peoples, to be mine.. REBA says: Where can we learn that a man doesn't say "I am not attracted by Shaatnez clothes, by swine meat, by prohibited relatinship; but I am and I am (attracted), but what can I do, my Father in Heaven decided!"? We learn this from "I will separate you from nations to be mine."